# How to add phonetic guides to all the texts at once?

Tags: ms-word

I have an essay with roughly 1000 Chinese words.  I want to add phonetic guide (Pin Yin) on top of each Chinese word.

Therefore, in MS Words, I use Phonetic Guide.  However, Phonetic Guide only allows me to create Pin Yin for 20 to 30 words each time.  I tried to look for a function which allows me to add phonetic guides for all the words at once, but I cannot find an answer online.

I also want to make the phonetic guide font bigger and create more space between the Chinese text and the Pin Yin.

Can any expert give me some lights?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with this area, but the starting point is that you can invoke the Phonetic Guide dialog box and get it to create the pinyin for the selection. For example

```
Sub testInsertPhoneticGuide()
Call insertPhoneticGuide(Selection.Range)
End Sub
Sub insertPhoneticGuide(r As Word.Range)
Dim d As Word.Dialog
Dim lng As Long
Dim lngChars As Long
Dim r1 As Word.Range
Dim r2 As Word.Range
On Error Resume Next
Set d = Word.Dialogs(wdDialogPhoneticGuide)
Set r1 = r.Duplicate
r1.TextRetrievalMode.IncludeFieldCodes = False
For lng = Len(r1.Text) To 1 Step -1
  Set r2 = r1.Characters(lng)
  ' Do not insert pinyin for any range that
  ' contains a field (this will prevent the code from re-inserting
  ' pinyin, but you can change the way this works if you like)
  If r2.Fields.Count = 0 Then
    r2.Select
    d.Show 1
    ' Error 6031 says there's no text to pinyin
    If Err.Number = 6031 Then
      Err.Clear
    Else
      On Error GoTo 0
    End If
  End If
Next
Set r2 = Nothing
Set r1 = Nothing
Set d = Nothing
End Sub
```

As far as I can tell, there is no way to specify the font and size/position parameters in the dialog box. They are not "sticky". But the Phonetic guide replaces each suitable character by an { EQ } field that contains the pinyin and the original character.  The EQ looks somehting like this:

```
{ EQ \* jc2 \* "Font:SimSun" \* hps11 \o\ad(\s\up 10(fā),发) }
```

so as long as you want the same font, size and positioning, you should be able to display all the field codes and use Word Find/Replace to modify those values in every EQ field (or you could add code to modify the values for each character that you pinyin.

NB, there is also a PhoneticGuide() member of Word's Range object that lets you specify the pinyin text and the positioning parameters. However, to use that you would have to get the pinyin text somehow - the only way I know within Word is actually to use the Phonetic Guide dialog to insert it, but I imagine the necessary info for each character is available on the web.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody comes to this question again, after searching for a solution for a while I managed to add pinyin to my entire Chinese document by using the following two tools:

1) [Open Office](https://www.openoffice.org/)

2) The [OO Pinyin Guide](https://sourceforge.net/projects/oopinyinguide/) Extension for Open Office.

Hope this helps : )