# How to add/remove phonetic guides by VBA on MS Word?

Tags: windows, vba, ms-word

Environment: Windows, MS Word, VBA.

How to add and remove phonetic guides by VBA on MS Word? 
I use the information in this link.
[How to add phonetic guides to all the texts at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602598/how-to-add-phonetic-guides-to-all-the-texts-at-once)

Add phonetic guides work!

Now, how to remove the phonetic guides?

Thanks in advance,
hashi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple. **No VBA is needed.** Just

1. **Copy** all.
2. Start a new document and **paste** as text.
3. By using "Find and Replace", **replace** all the **blankets** `(  )` to **nothing**. The steps are as below:

   1. In "*Find what*", **type** `\(*\)` and **empty** "*Replace with*".
   2. **Click** on "*More >>*" and **check** "*Use Wildcards*".
   3. **Click** on "*Replace All*".
4. If the original format is needed, Just "***Copy Format***" from the original document.

**Note:** If the content have any **blankets** (before doing the above steps), **replace** all the `(` and `)` to **any** other **characters**. After doing the above steps, **replace** the characters **back** to `(` and `)`.